# Scipy: solve quadratic with double summation

Tags: scipy, mathematical-optimization, quadratic-programming

I'm relatively new to scipy and I'm looking for a guidance. 
I have an unconstrained minimization problem of the form:

[image: function]

Where a and b are coefficients and x is a vector of unknowns (can be of different length). I'm wondering about how to solve this problem using python. I looked through the [scipy reference guide](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html#scipy.optimize.leastsq) but couldn't find the answer.

Thank you

Comment: Start by checking out the [tutorial](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/tutorial/optimize.html) and not the API-reference. It's very easy (to implement *something*; it might not be the best) and those examples should be enough to get you going.

Comment: Could you show your attempts and where you got stuck?

Answer (score -2):

Let A be the sum of the a's and X that of the x's. Then you want to choose X to minimise

```
Sum{ i | square( A-X-b[i])}
```

The value of X that minimises this will be the mean (over i) of A-b[i], that is A - mean(b)

Comment: This does not answer the question of how to apply Python to the problem. Just because the question is bad does not mean that your answer can be as well.